# How to avoid variable after statement `for` in python?

Tags: python

When I write programs with python, something offen happens like:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("before",i)
    for j in range(5):
        for i in range(5):
            pass
    print("after",i)
```

which output:

```
before 0
after 4
before 1
after 4
before 2
after 4
before 3
after 4
before 4
after 4
```

I often use variables with the same name in the outer loop and multiple inner loops, which will cause bugs but are hard to find. What is the best practice to avoid this situation?

What I mean is that when I focus on writing business code, it is difficult for me to detect or often ignore the problem of duplicate variable names, which wastes a lot of debugging time. In fact, I have been writing code in a C-like style. I'm trying to find a way to stop getting this type of error

Comment: Use more descriptive names

Comment: ... to not use variables with same name?

Comment: Use a static code analysis tool like `pycodestyle` or `pylint` or perhaps `mypy`

Comment: "In fact, I have been writing code in a C-like style. " that's bad. Python and C are *very different langauges*. The looping constructs are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 4):

Use different names! There's no way to re-use a variable name in any scope.

Answer (score 4):

Use a linter, e.g. `pylint`.  The purpose of a linter is to help you catch things that are syntactically valid but are considered bad practice, bad style, or likely to be mistakes.

```
>pylint test.py
************* Module test
test.py:4:8: W0621: Redefining name 'i' from outer scope (line 1) (redefined-outer-name)
```

Comment: Or any IDE with syntax highlight.

Comment: Syntax highlight in itself won't do it, but most IDEs do have linting built in and will highlight lint errors for you.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've meant.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you should not do that.
As you have said it makes things way more complicated than it ought to be :D

You could just name them like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("before",i)
    for i2 in range(5):
        for i3 in range(5):
            pass
    print("after",i)
```

If you are using them in the same block of code, they should be  at least not named the same.

But thats just my opinion about it.

Comment: iterator is a bad name here, because iterator has a specific meaning in Python, and your `iterator` variables *do not contain iterators*

Comment: It has? I am not aware of that, its not reserved by python itself or am I missing something? :D

Comment: An *iterator* is a type of object. Specifically, it is an object that defines an `__iter__` method (which should just `return self`) along with a `__next__` method.  It's like defining `mylist = 1`, it is confusing because your variable named `mylist` actually refers to an `int`, not a `list`, as the name would imply.

Comment: Ahh thats how you meant it, yeah you are right, I will change the name of the variable, that was just for presenting purposes :D

Comment: This code doesn't actually run because you're still printing `i`.  The idiomatic thing IMO would be to name the three loop variables `i`, `j`, and `k` if you can't think of a usefully descriptive name given the context.

Answer (score -1):

Use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm) IDE. It will show you a warning message:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Minimize number of nested loops, too.  That is an indirect indication that code is suboptimal, at least from readability point of view.

Comment: No, no it isnt.

Comment: I'm also not sure that this is actually an answer to the provided question.

Comment: @Jesse, the question is "What is the best practice to avoid this situation?".  Minimizing number of nested loops helps with that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, agree to disagree, I guess.  In my book, loop within a loop per function is the hard limit.